# ember.js instantiate first record from ember-data query in router

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I want to build a ember route that uses the attribute "name" to find a user record.

The problem is the show action of the restful backend, it is not configured to use "name" as the finder.

So I would like to query the backend index action using "name" and instantiate the first record returned in the collection.

It seems to me this should be possible using ember-data.

Here is the ember route:

```
edit: Em.Route.extend
  route: '/:name/edit'

  deserialize: (router, params) ->
    user = router.get('store').findQuery( App.User, { name: params.name } )
    #return user[0]
    #return user.get('content')[0]
    return user

  serialize: (router, user) ->
    name: user.get('name')

  connectOutlets: (router, user) ->
    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('user', user)
```

Any one have any ideas?

SOLUTION USING DAN'S SUGGESTION

```
 loading: Em.State.extend()

 edit: Em.Route.extend
  route: '/:name/edit'

  deserialize: (router, params) ->
    user = router.get('store').findQuery( App.User, { name: params.name } )
    deferred = $.Deferred()
    user.addObserver "isLoaded", -> deferred.resolve( user.materializedObjectAt(0) )
    return deferred.promise()

  serialize: (router, user) ->
    name: user.get('name')

  connectOutlets: (router, user) ->
    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('user', user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to implement async routing, because `findQuery` is an async method. Check out Luke Melia's slidedeck on the topic (esp. slide 11):

http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/09/18/async-routing-in-ember-js/